# Return a const vector of const shared pointers to const objects

Tags: c++, stl, constants, shared-ptr

Given the following class based on containers of shared pointers,

```
class Foo;

class Bar {
public:
  // ...
  const std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<const Foo> >& getFoos() const { return foos_; }
private:
  std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > foos_;
};
```

which will not compile because

```
invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<const Foo>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<const Foo> > >&’ from expression of type ‘const std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Foo>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > >’
```

The `foos_` member needs to point to mutable `Foo` objects for internal use by the `Bar` object, but I don't want client code calling `getFoos()` to be able to modify anything.

Removing the `const` qualifier from `Foo` in the `getFoos()` return type fixes this. However, I understand that while `std::vector` propagates its constness to its elements, `boost::shared_ptr` does no such thing to the object it points to (naturally). Thus, it seems to me `getFoos()` no longer observes its `const` qualifier (even though the compiler doesn't complain), because client code can modify the `Foo` objects pointed to by the shared pointers returned.

Am I correct? If so, is there some way to write `getFoos()` so that it will return a const vector of const references to const objects without copying?

Comment: What does `Bar`'s caller do with the `vector` once it gets the reference to it?

Comment: It *should* do read-only operations on its elements (or, more precisely, on the objects to which its elements point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong but I really don't think you can achieve this.

`shared_ptr<Foo>` can become a `shared_ptr<const Foo>` only through a construction of a new instance to `shared_ptr<const Foo>`

A reference to `shared_ptr<Foo>` cannot become a reference to `shared_ptr<const Foo>`, simply because they are two **different** types.

Here you are trying to get a reference to `vector<shared_ptr<Foo>>` into the form of `const vector<shared_ptr<const Foo>>`.

The first `const` is perfectly fine. Since it's okay to assign a reference to the same reference type with a const qualifier.

But the second `const` is not, as you are literally trying to convert a reference to a vector of `Type A` to a reference to a vector of `Type B`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning a `std::vector<...> const&`, what about returning a range?  A range is a `pair` of iterators of some kind.  In this case, your iterators will be to `std::shared_ptr<const foo>`.  You can do this by writing up a quick iterator adapter that internally iterates over `const_iterator` to `std::shared_ptr<foo>`, but returns them as `std::shared_ptr<const foo>`.

Most operations you'll want to perform on a `const` `vector` can be performed on a `range` of random-access `const_iterator`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `const shared_ptr<Foo>*` pointer instead of a vector, and use explicit ugly C-style casting to convert `foos_.data()` into whatever you want.

Since you're interested in returning a const vector, you don't lose much by returning a pointer, except sizing information, of course. You can always wrap the new pointer in a class designed to provide this sizing information, as supplied at moment of its creation.