# Shared pointers and constness of pointed-to object

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

If I have a class, say,

```
class Car {
  public:
    void Drive();
    void DisplayMileage() const;
};
```

And I create a shared pointer based on this class,

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Car> CarPtr;
```

And I then go on to populate a vector of CarPtrs,

```
std::vector<CarPtrs> cars...;
```

I now want to iterate over the vector and do some stuff:

```
for(auto const &car : cars) {
   car->DisplayMileage(); // I want this to be okay
   car->Drive(); // I want the compilation to fail here because Drive isn't const.
}
```

Is this possible without casting the shared pointer to a car to a shared pointer to a const car?

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr<Car const>`?

Comment: I want to make just this particular iteration over the vector fail on const, I might want to alter the car in another iteration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15164330/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/q/13464199/560648

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a good use case for [the Boost.Range "indirected" adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indirected.html):

```
for(auto const& car : cars | boost::adaptors::indirected) {
  car.DisplayMileage();
  car.Drive(); // error: passing 'const Car' as 'this' argument of 'void Car::Drive()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
}
```

Working demo code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=888305887c8b4e6285c0bd6cee1ca60a-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to do without changing the original definition, it was an academic exercise, but great answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible **without casting the shared pointer to a car to a shared pointer to a const car**?

No, it is not possible. The `const` applies to the shared pointer, not to the thing it refers to.

This is a basic fact of indirection, and it is the same with pointers:

```
int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   int* p1 = &x;
   auto const p2 = p1;

   // p2 is `int* const`, not `int const*`
   *p1 = 1;
}
```

It's arguably unfortunate that there's simply no way to inherently gain immutability in your iteration, but that's because you're employing indirection: you're not iterating over `Car`s.

Comment: Sometimes, my favorite part of SO is "no, it is not possible" answers (which make perfect sense, and are correct!) immediately adjacent to "sure, this is easy with `boost`" answers.